# How do I know if users have really turned GPS/Network on after directing them to the settings page?

Tags: android, gps, settings, provider

I am building a location finding application which requires GPS or Network operations. I want to be able to direct users to the GPS or the Wireless settings to force them to turn it on if they don't have it on. My question is, how do I check if they really have turned the providers on after the settings page?

Below is the usual code to direct users to the settings. What would I do after that?

```
LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabled = service
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!enabled) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would I do after that?

Nothing.

You are presumably (hopefully?) checking whether you can use GPS in `onResume()` of your activity. That logic will be invoked again when control returns to your activity from the Settings activity. Hence, you will go through the same logic again.

Comment: Thanks. Does this therefore not mean I would have exactly the same code afterwards i.e. I would have the same bit of code where I handle result when a provider is enabled

Comment: @JohnathanAu: `startActivity()` is asynchronous. I do not know what "handle result when a provider is enabled" means. If you mean in your `LocationListener`, I would *strongly* encourage you to *not* just throw them back into the Settings activity. If they just disabled GPS, **they probably have a reason**. Handle it more gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity.  Then in onActivityResult check isProviderEnabled again.  This should work, unless idProviderEnabled won't return true until you have GPS synch, which I don't think is the case.  Same thing should work for wifi.